# Javascript onsubmit successive functions

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

I have a form with a javascript to validate mandatory fields, and another one to force php server messages to show up in a pop up window.

Also, in case javascript is disabled, I have a php validator in the server.

I want the pop up function to work if the javascript validator has no messages.

Right now, when I leave a mandatory field empty, I get the message from the javascript validator, and also a pop up window with the php validation message:

```
form action="http://myserver.com/formmail.php" method="post" name="SampleForm"  onsubmit="return (validateForm() || createTarget(this.target)" target="formtarget")"
```

I m not sure if I was clear...Any help? Thank you!

Comment: Please post your validateform() function, in addition to your createTarget() function.

Comment: Probably not related, but you're missing a parenthesis. I assume it should read `"return (validateForm() || createTarget(this.target))"` EDIT: Although I just realised there's also a stray parenthesis at the end, so I'm not entirely sure what it's supposed to be now...

Comment: `Also, in case javascript is disabled, I have a php validator in the server.` You **must** validate on the server anyway, you have no reliable way to know if javascript is disabled or not, or whether the data you get successfully passed validation, or even came from a browser or the form you served.

Answer (score 0):

As best I can work out, your requirement is that on submit you want to call the `validateForm()` function first, and if it returns `false` stop processing and stop the submit. Otherwise if `validateForm()` returns `true`, you want to call `createTarget()` and allow the submit to continue. You can achieve this by using an AND instead of OR condition, i.e., use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
onsubmit="return (validateForm() && createTarget(this.target));"
```

Note that you were missing the closing `)`, although you don't need the outer parentheses at all:

```
onsubmit="return validateForm() && createTarget(this.target);"
```

The reason your code didn't work with `||` is that if the left-hand operand is `false` (or falsy) then the right-hand operand is evaluated and the result of the whole expression is the value of the right-hand operand. If the left-hand operand is `true` (or truthy) the right-hand operand isn't evaluated at all. So if your `validateForm()` returned false because there was a validation error the `createTarget()` function would still be called and if it returned a value other than `false` the submit would continue.

(Of course I'm assuming that `validateForm()` returns `true` if there are no errors and `false` if there are errors.)

For more information, read up on [JavaScript's logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators).